# Android: Go back to previous activity & minimize the activiy?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to do something simple on android app. How is it possible to go back to a previous activity.

What code do I need to go back to previous activity & minimize the activity

Comment: You want to go back to previous activity on click of back button?

Comment: Programmatically, try `finish` or call `super.onBackPressed()`, that'll work similar to a back button press

Comment: Fortunately you have to do nothing, its all automatic in Android. Just press back button.

Answer (score 0):

In Android activity, if you are not writing any fancy stuff, ideally on back button press activity will be finished, If you want to have a button and on click of button you want activity to go back , just call `finish()` in your `button` `onClickListener()`

Answer (score 0):

just call `finish()` or `onBackPress()` , if you want to go back  on click of any view then call the above one in `OnClick(View v)` of button else just press back it will automatically call `OnBackPress()`